# defining and accessing a list of custom objects

Tags: python, list, object

I have an object

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self):
    price = float(0)
```

Then another

```
class Day:
  def __init__(self):
    self.carList = [Car() for each in range(100)]
    self.createPriceList()

  def createPriceList(self):
    tempCar = Car()
    for i in range(100):
      tempCar.price = function_giving_a_value() # 10 last cars have 0.0 as value
      self.carList[i] = tempCar
      print i, self.carList[i].price 
# prints the correct list : each line contains a correct price
#edited after answers : in fact it's just misleading, cf answers

  def showPriceList(self):
    for i in range(len(self.carList)):
      print i, self.carList[i].price 
# prints i (correct) but each self.carList[i].price as 0.0
# so len(self.carList) gives correct value, 
# but self.carList[i].price a wrong result
```

My question is :

- Why in `showPriceList()`, `self.carList` is correctly recognized (`len` gives the correct number in looping) but `self.carList[i].price` gives only zeros? (when it seems correctly filled in method `createPriceList()`)

Comment: I would expect all prices to be the same, but I wouldn't expect all prices to be zero, but rather some random value.

Comment: I prefer `price = 0.0` rather than `price = float(0)`

Comment: @ Marnach, correct in fact i put random() but it was a wrong idea. function_giving_a_price() returns 0.0 for the last 10 cars. i amended my original question

Answer (score 4):

<strike>The most likely explanation is that you don't actually call `createPriceList()` before calling `showPriceList()`.</strike> [**edit**: now that you've edited the code in your question, we can eliminate this possibility]

Also, `createPriceList()` has an error whereby you assign references to the same `Car` object to all elements of the list. This error could also explain the behaviour, if and only if the last <strike>`random()`</strike> `function_giving_a_value()` call returns zero.

Finally, you're missing `self.` in a couple of places [**edit**: again, you seem to have fixed some of these in a recent edit].

Here is how I would have written it:

```
import random

class Car:

    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price

class Day:

  def __init__(self, n):
      self.carList = []
      for i in range(n): # could also use list comprehension here
          self.carList.append(Car(random.random()))

  def printPriceList(self):
      for i, car in enumerate(self.carList):
        print(i, car.price)

day = Day(20)
day.printPriceList()
```

Comment: Did you look at the code of `createPriceList()`?  It sets all items of the list to the same object.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Yes, I was typing that into my answer as you were typing your question :-)

Comment: Ah, I see.  Still very surprising that `random.random()` returns exactly zero. :)

Comment: well, in fact createPriceList() was called in __init__ (my mistake creating this code example). and in my example i used random() first but in real code it's not random() but a function giving a price. this function works fine, tested.

Comment: you're right, only reference was assigned, so when i changed value of tempCar.price, it changed for all "items" in list. thx all for your precious help. i was stuck all day on it !

Comment: The OP code is wrong because he creates a single instance of `theCar` object and adds that object to his list. Any change on that object is reflected in all its "views" which are all the list elements.

Comment: @jsbueno: I take it you've read the second paragraph of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're using the for loop in a 'wrong' way. You're creating an index from the length of a list, and then accesing elements from that same list using this index. This can be simplified, take for example your createPriceList method, it could look like this:

```
def createPriceList(self):
    for car in self.carList
        car.price = random()
        print car.price
```

What you did in your example, is create one car before the loop, and changing it's value every time you store the car. That means that your carlist will be filled with references to the same car, so they will all have the same price.

The zeros are because random() returns a floating point number between 0 and 1. If this number is smaller then 0.1, the printed version will look like 0.0

Comment: hum i'm not sure because : print i, self.carList[i].price returns really what i want : each line shows a different price.

Comment: thats because you printed right after assigning the price. If you would prinr self.carList[i-1].price, you'd see that it prints the same value as self.carList[i]

Comment: @ Creemers : you're totally right, self.carList[i-1].price prints same as self.carList[i].price

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to acheive, it might be better to keep single attributes for single Car()s, and build a list of Car() instances outside of the class:

```
import random

class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.price = random.random()

class Day:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cars = [Car() for each in range(100)]

day = Day()
priceList = [car.price for car in day.cars]
```

The priceList should not exist within the class since it is redundant, in my opinion.